# selecting Id that do not follow the css syntax

Tags: javascript

```html
<div id="foo\bar"></div>
<div id="foo:bar"></div>
```

```js
document.querySelector('#foo\\\\bar'); // Match the first div
```

In the official doc it is mention that to match ID or selectors that do not follow the CSS syntax (by using a colon or space inappropriately for example), you must escape the character with a back slash.

As the backslash is an escape character in JavaScript, if you are entering a literal string, you must escape it twice (once for the JavaScript string, and another time for querySelector) but in the above code they have used backslash three times.

I am unable to understand this logic.

Comment: _"in the above code they have used backslash three times"_ <- I count **four**

Comment: Better use document.getElementById("foo\\bar");

Answer (score 0):

If we need to escape it twice, it will be unescaped twice too:

```
1. \\\\ -> \\
2. \\ -> \
```